# Why jquery post method doesnt read response and give error with asp.net oauth rediction

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We got ASP.NET MVC 4 server template with OAuth Authentication. Our goal is login with Facebook by sending jquery post to our server that redirects us to facebook's login. But problem is we always get inexplicable error and didnt get anything response. "errorThrown" is blank. If we use Fiddler2 debugger, we get 302 result, but jQuery give only error. Why jquery doesnt give any reason why error happening and how we fix this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/Account/ExternalLogin?RedirectUrl=",
    data: "provider=facebook",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('success');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
    },                     
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert('complete');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

FIDDLER2 DATA:

Sended:

POST http://ourserver.cloudapp.net/Account/ExternalLogin/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ourserver.cloudapp.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17
Accept: */*
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

provider=facebook

Received:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: provider_%3Dfacebook%26_*sid*_%3D13245678b123456ab06fe89bb2f096e0&scope=email">https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789012345&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fourserver.cloudapp.net%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3F_*provider*_%3Dfacebook%26_*sid*_%3D13245678b123456ab06fe89bb2f096e0&scope=email
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: **csid**=02WGEfG8OwBHUWBZ0bzYzqNxFadqDDTwp8XD7-Mmugetev_2DV3WcD1vljqAaw5POPQFJA2; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 28 Apr 2013 23:01:52 GMT

162
Object moved

### Object moved to [here](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789012345&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fourserver.cloudapp.net%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3F__provider__%3Dfacebook%26__sid__%3D13245678b123456ab06fe89bb2f096e0&scope=email).

0